# Fatal Error When starting network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am following this tutorial https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html Where i have successfully generated my channel by using ./byfn.sh -m generate / up Now trying to start the network by using

```
# command: /bin/bash -c './scripts/script.sh ${CHANNEL_NAME}; sleep $TIMEOUT'
```

I have faced following error :

```
Channel name : mychannel
Creating channel...
panic: Fatal error when initializing core config : Error when reading core config file: 
        Unsupported Config Type ""goroutine 1 [running]:panic(0xbb8400, 0xc0421fd4b0)
        /opt/go/go1.7.linux.amd64/src/runtime/panic.go:500
        +0x1afmain.main()/w/workspace/fabric-binaries-x86_64/gopath/src/github.com/
                  hyperledger/fabric/peer/main.go:94 +0x859
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Channel creation failed !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
========= ERROR !!! FAILED to execute End-2-End Scenario ===========
```

Comment: Does [this bug report apply to you](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-3438)?

Comment: No this doesn't as i am facing this error on Starting Network

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. If you have executed the ./byfn.sh -m generate and the ./byfn.sh -m up, you should have your network started up. Why are you trying to start up it again?

Answer (score 0):

I think the network was not ready to run that script.
Please modify the command like this:

## command: /bin/bash -c 'sleep 10s; ./scripts/script.sh ${CHANNEL_NAME}; sleep $TIMEOUT'

Comment: No luck even by modifying sleep to 10s i am still facing the same error